# How to use parameterize in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to convert the title of a page to a friendly URL and store it in the database as a permalink. My problem is I can't use the `parameterize` method. It's not working. Other inflections are working like `upcase` or `downcase` but `parameterize` is not working. Is there a special case for `parameterize`?

This is my code:

Controller:

```
def create
 params[:page][:permalink] = params[:page][:title].dup
 @page = Page.new(params[:page])
end
```

Model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_save :makeitpermalink
 before_update :makeitpermalink

 private
  def makeitpermalink
    permalink.parameterize!
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, glad to see rails enthusiasts here. Next time try to use code formating and give your question a better title in order to get responses. I just edited your post, but just so you know. About the question I don't know. Could you provide the error message or result you're getting?

Comment: In the model, you also only need to have the before_save callback; before_update is unnecessary.

Comment: btw if u have "before_save", "before_update" is redundant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Rails' documentation, there is no bang (exclamation mark) version of the `parameterize` method, so try removing it:

```
def make_it_permalink
  self.permalink = self.permalink.parameterize
end
```

Comment: If I understand what he's trying to do here, this would probably have to be: self.permalink = self.permalink.parameterize